# django cart.js loop is not running

Tags: javascript, python, django, e-commerce, cart

cart.js
this is not working
nothing is printed in the console or some declaration is wrong
answer quickly

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for(var i=0 ; i<updateBtns.length ; i++)
{
    updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        var productId = this.dataset.product
        var action = this.dataset.action
        console.log(productId,action)

    })
}
```

is there any mistake in html code

```
 {% for product in products %}
    {% if product.category == "Dosa" %}
    <div class="product">        
    <tr>
      <td><h5>{{ product.name }}</h5></td>
      <td><h5>{{ product.price }}</h5></td>
      <td><button data-product={{product.id}} data-action="add" class="btn btn-warning btn-add update-cart">Add to cart</button></td>
    </tr>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Make sure your JavaScript is run only after the body is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Seems to be working perfectly. I would suggest to please check once in incognito/Private mode. Might be a problem of cache...